# Is it possible to play games on Playstation 4 / Xbox One with keyboard and mouse?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

I play games on my laptop. I tried playing on a PS3 and Xbox 360 on my friend's consoles and I am not at all comfortable with the controllers. Actually, I lost every round so I can't play.

Can I connect a keyboard and mouse to the new PS4 or Xbox One and play games? Is it possible?

Comment: On PS4, at least, some games can theoretically support it (see: Final Fantasy XIV on PS4 can be played with a keyboard and mouse), but it seems to be very, very rare.

Comment: Xbox One will be getting mouse support natively. Had to do research to determine if buying a third party converter was worth it, but Microsoft confirmed "probably in this or next months update"

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer it was a two player match that i was killed in the first ten seconds every round so you are more than welcome to enjoy it this way in your generation.

Comment: I spoke with Microsoft, yesterday. Their representative confirmed that mouse support is still being released, and said to expect it in this or next months update. I went out of my way to ask because I was getting anxious and almost purchased a converter.

Comment: Well actually many modern games are designed to exactly fit the design of controllers, and using mouse+keyboard will inevitably be less efficient if you master them both. Clear examples are FIFA/PES, NBA 2K, Diablo III etc. So it will do you no harm in picking up your skills in controllers, especially since many of your friends are likely to have only controllers. Maybe you can just buy a cheap one and start using it on your PC.

Comment: @XiangJi   Well i don't play sports games and the only games i can play with controller are racing games so there would be no advantage for me to learn this skill, and your comment is exactly the opposite of my question and it's answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The PS3 and PS4 both support keyboards and mice, [the Xbox 360 only supports keyboard but not mice, and the Xbox One doesn't appear to support either for now. It is said that the Xbox One *might* eventually get support for keyboard and mouse with Windows 10 for Xbox.](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/xbox-one-keyboard-and-mouse-support-possible/1100-6415435/)

Unfortunately, the games need to support keyboard and mouse as well, and not many do. Games that support those peripherals include [*Unreal Tournament 3*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Tournament_3#PlayStation_3_version) (PS3) which also supports mods, [*Final Fantasy XIV: A Realm Reborn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIV:_A_Realm_Reborn#Interface) (PS3 & PS4), [Dust 514](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2012/08/09/dust-514-update-adds-eve-online-integration-keyboard-and-mouse-controls-and-more/), and apparently *War Thunder* (PS4) too.

In the end, keyboard and mouse support on PS3/PS4 is mainly useful for browsing the internet, but they *do* support them nonetheless.

Comment: I don't have the game, but I think Counter-Strike: GO for PS3 supports keyboard and mouse as well.

Comment: I could swear I've used a USB keyboard on the 360 for the purpose of typing messages.

Comment: A keyboard was also the recommended way to play e.g. FFXI on the XBox 360. I'm also pretty sure you can use a USB keyboard to do *some* things on the XBox One, just not playing games since pretty much none support it AFAIK.

Comment: @Random832. Thanks, I made some more research, and found out that the Xbox 360 *does* support keyboards, but not mice. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The Windows 10 update has already been released, and has not brought with it mouse and keyboard support. It was originally required for Windows 10 to allow streaming, but they since implemented an alternate work around. Microsoft has confirmed that mouse is on its way, at least.

Comment: Dust 514 is another title supporting Keyboard & Mouse on PS3, adding it above.

Comment: The X1 does indeed support keyboards, but on the SO level - there are no implementation on it's interface for it, no namespace avaliable to deal with such implementations, and no official docs on how to yet. You can read a little more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532261(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 7):

For actual gaming you can use a Keymander (given you are willing to purchase one). It converts the keyboard and mouses inputs into controller inputs.

http://www.iogear.com/product/GE1337P/

Comment: +1 I might actually buy one of this things. Finally a way to show the console-fanboys I know that keyboard and mouse really is more suited to play shooters.

Answer (score 4):

The different consoles have different support for keyboard and mouse.

All the consoles, PS3, PS4, Xbox 360 and Xbox one, support a keyboard for textual input. You can thus use it to type in messages to friends, naming things like characters in games, etc. Most places where you can enter text a keyboard can be used. Some of the consoles even have built-in bluetooth support, but they should all support a keyboard that uses a wireless usb plug. Some games build their own quirky text input on-screen keyboards and sometimes these doesn't support a physical keyboard.

For mouse, it depends. Xbox 360 and Xbox One has no support for mouse at all, in fact Microsoft has not enabled / made available drivers that can communicate with a mouse. That is not to say that a developer cannot access the USB drivers and talk to a mouse directly, and thus just implement basic support themselves, but there is no system support for it. I have no idea how close a developer might come if they tried though.

For PS3 and PS4 the case is apparently different, as is evident from the other answer here, even having 2-3 games that support it. (there are probably more than 2-3, but this is something each game will need to add themselves, the platform doesn't give you built-in always-on support for playing games with a mouse and keyboard).

Microsoft has, with their release of Windows 10, promised to reevaluate mouse and keyboard support on Xbox One, but this would be to control games on a PC, streaming them to a console and thus playing on a big-screen TV. You would then still be playing "on a PC", only using the Xbox One as a networked thin client for the PC. This would not be the same as allowing games on the console to use keyboard and mouse.

As such, in general, almost no games on the consoles allow keyboard and mouse. Microsoft has, to my knowledge, been asked a couple of times by games developers and have denied access to this each time, Sony with Playstation has apparently opened up somewhat.

It is, however, really rare that a console game *would* allow a keyboard and mouse, as this would no longer be a level playing field between people with and people without that hardware connected.

Microsoft had a brief stint when they experimented with [Shadowrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowrun_(2007_video_game)) where they enabled cross-platform playing between PC gamers and Xbox 360 gamers.

The PC gamers used a keyboard and mouse, and the Xbox 360 gamers used their controller. They could, however, play against and with each other on common servers.

Some mitigating factors were introduced in an attempt to level the playing field, notably increased hitboxes for console gamers. Thus PC gamers was both expected and required to be more accurate when shooting, compared to their console opponents.

While the game had mixed reviews for the game that it delivered, I consider it telling that Microsoft, or anyone else, has to this date not yet released another competitive AA-game with this kind of support.

The exact same problem with a level playing field would be present if a game on a console allowed people to play with both a keyboard and mouse, as well as a controller, thus "nobody" does it, or at least that is my theory. If you want to know why 343 Studios didn't develop Halo 5 with keyboard and mouse support you probably will have to ask them directly.

So, as the other answer here proves, technologically, Playstation allows both mouse and keyboard, while *very* few games actually take advantage of it, and the Microsoft platform doesn't support it at all.

In the spirit of the original question, which asked "can i connect keyboard and mouse to the new ps4 or xbox One and play games", I still feel the correct answer is no. You can't. Not because you technically can't, but because "nobody" builds games that support this and Microsoft even goes as far as not allowing it.

---

**Hackish solutions**

In a comment to this answer I also said that there are 3rd party solutions to this. These have varying support for the different consoles, some are specialized towards one console platform or even just one console, some are for every console and platform ("every" in this context means PS3, PS4, Xbox 360 and Xbox One).

These work by allowing you to connect a keyboard and a mouse to a 3rd party device, usually also connecting said device to a real controller, and connecting the whole shebang into the console. Whenever you press a key on the keyboard, or move the mouse, the device will translate this into the appropriate controller button or stick and simulate the player using the real controller.

Some of these "solutions" are clunky, where the "device" is basically a USB device which has to be plugged into a full computer, others are better and probably more expensive.

They all fall prey to the "level playing field" problem, in which a game that has no concept of keyboard and mouse control suddenly has players that can play with a lot higher accuracy than their opponents has entered the game. [Example: XIM3: Mouse and Keyboard on Xbox 360](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnZvrjv1_JI). Yes, there are *really* good players out there there are plenty of Youtube videos where you can hear the person playing bragging about "upping his game with a XIM3".

Comment: There *are* 3rd party solutions that basically mimick a controller when communicating with the console and takes input from keyboard and mouse and translates it but I consider this cheating so I won't recommend this.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. I myself have a bluetooth keyboard hooked up to my PS3 & PS4. It's a standard bluetooth keyboard. The issue is that few games support it. However browsing the internet works. The other answer is the correct answer.

Comment: When Dust 514 came out on the PS3 it was a huge deal that you could use keyboard/mouse. I imagine the functionality carries over to the PS4 as well.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen  You said in your comment above you consider the use of 3rd party solution cheating  - Please could you explain this, After all I would assume that any 3rd party solution would increase command lag therefore negating any advantage which (may) be gained through the use of mouse/keyboard

Comment: No, they work really well, to the point where people are playing Call of Duty with sniper rifles at short distances.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Nitpicking but I never said that a keyboard was unsupported by the console. The question asks if games can be played and though the other answer proves that yes, a few games does in fact support it, I never said you could not type text with it. I have expanded on the answer in any case now.

Comment: @EdHunter He means something like this. It's not really a keyboard as much as a PS4 controller that has a keyboard layout. http://www.gamespot.com/articles/officially-licensed-ps4-mouse-and-keyboard-control/1100-6429210/

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Nitpicking but what you said was "No, it is not possible" when the actual answer is "Yes, it is possible but unlikely." It's not hard to see my original objection. The answer was flat-out wrong. That being said, this answer is much better than your original. It's unfortunate that It's already been downvoted so much. It's clear that you just wanted to help someone out. :)